# O Conteúdo estático da jsp não aparece

Tags: css, netbeans, spring-mvc, jsp

Estou utilizando o netbeans 7.3.1, aparentemente ele está funcionando ok. As páginas estão abrindo normalmente, porém quando tento acessar o conteúdo css, jpg, ... dentro da pasta resources, não aparece nenhum conteúdo.

No arquivo dispatcher-servlet.xml coloquei as seguinte linha:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

e no index.jsp, coloquei a chamada da seguinte forma:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>`

[image: organização do sistema]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Problema foi solucionado.

A questão era o local onde a pasta resources estava, por algum motivo, como "utluiz" havia mencionado, não estava no local correto, pois se tratava de uma outra pasta. Então criei uma pasta "resources" na pasta "web app" da seguinte forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não precisou realizar nenhum mapeamento no "dispatcher-servlet.xml". Por isso, foram retiradas as linhas que havia colocado

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você colocou as imagens e estilos num diretório de `resources`. Embora seja o mesmo nome que você está usando, isso não é a mesma coisa.

Note que o título do elemento superior é "Outros Códigos-fonte". Esses `resources` na verdade são os usados na aplicação Java, como arquivos de configuração.

O local correto para os estilos e imagens é dentro de "Páginas Web".

Supondo que você mova as duas pastas para dentro de "Páginas Web", sugiro mudar sua anotação da seguinte forma:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

Note que o atributo `location` faz referência à raiz da aplicação, que é "Páginas Web". Na verdade, se o Netbeans está seguindo a estrutura do Maven, essa pasta é `src/main/webapp`, mas ele acaba escondendo o local verdadeiro. Esse é o local que deve receber os recursos do webapp.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Infelizmente ainda continuo com o mesmo problema. Coloquei as pastas dentro o webapp (sim está seguindo a estrutura o maven); substituí o seguinte código no arquivo dispatcher-servlet.xml

`<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />`

e fiz uma simples chamada na jsp para verificar se a imagem estava aparecendo
`<img src="img/calendario.jpg" />`

Será que está faltando algo?
Desculpe pelo incômodo. Sou novo no spring MVC :)